# Unable to install tweepy in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

When i'm trying to install tweepy in windows 10 for python 3.6 using conda by this command:

*conda install -c conda-forge tweepy*

after downloading all the required packages .It shows an error like this :

*ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::pyjwt-1.5.3-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist.*

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : `Click on start`


Step 2 : `Search and Open Anaconda Navigator`


Step 3 : In the Anaconda Navigator, `Go to Evironments`


Step 4 : `There is a drop down menu consisting of options : 1)Installed 2)Not Installed 3)Upgradable 4) Selected 5)All`


Step 5 : `Click on "Not Installed"`


Step 6 : `There is a block stating Search Packages, there enter the name of the package you want to install (in your case you want to install tweepy)`


Step 7 : `Mark the tweepy in the search results, and click Apply`


Installation will start.


Congratulations! You have successfully installed the package.